# Rails/Postgres: Column must appear in group by clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So Postgres is complaining about:

```
PGError: ERROR:  column "sessions.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

But the trouble is, "created_at" *does* appear in the group by clause:

```
SELECT     created_at, count(id) as visit_count FROM       "sessions"  WHERE     ("sessions"."site_id" IN (4, 3)) AND ("sessions"."created_at" >= '2011-10-20 00:00:00.000000') AND ("sessions"."created_at" <= '2011-10-27 23:59:59.999999') GROUP BY  date(created_at))
```

Does it have something to do with created_at being wrapped in date() perhaps?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not appear.

The GROUP BY contains `date(created_at)` whereas your SELECT list only contains `created_at`.  If `created_at` is a timestamp, then these are two different things.

You either need to use `GROUPY BY created_at` or `SELECT date(created_at)` (probably the latter)